# Best way to search through a object list to evaluate a certain variable from that object?

Tags: c#

I hope I am explaining this clearly. I'm trying to figure out a good (or the best) way to search through a list of objects to evaluate one particular variable before making a decision.

Imagine I have a List, the Person class contains three variables (Name, Age, Favorite color) and my list looks like below:

1. Bob, 69, Blue
2. Fred, 64, Green
3. Billy, 29, Yellow
4. Ted, 16, Orange

So my list contains 4 objects, and I would like to check the list to make sure that no one on the list is in the age range of 30 - 50. What is going to be the best way to do this?

my initial thought was to do a foreach loop, and for every iteration that a person's age is not in the 30 - 50 range I would increment a int variable. then at the end check to see if the int variable is equal to the count of the list. Sounds terrible thinking about it out loud, and if the list grew to 1000+ then I can imagine it wouldn't be the fastest way to look through the list and verify that no ones age falls within that range. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: `if( list.Any(x => x.Age >= 30 && x.Age <= 50 ) ) throw new ContainsIllegalAgeException();` ?

Comment: Unrelated: It's rarely a good idea to save "Age". In most cases, it's better to save date of birth and calculate age when needed.

Comment: Since I guess this is for some sort of coursework: Are you allowed to use Linq (that's what Ekas answer uses)? If not, you may want to mention that in the question.

Comment: I appreciate your input @Fildor. This was the easiest example that I could think of that would still be relevant to my problem.

Comment: I need to search through a much larger list of objects to check integer values that represent a position of a physical  object in space, and make sure there no physical objects within a certain boundary basically. Boolean return value is all I am looking for.

Comment: OK, so it's not _really_ an age ... in that case that comment does not apply, of course. However: How is the Position represented? With 3 Cartesian Coords? Or something else? Maybe Quarternions?

Comment: I am asking because if it is a really huge dataset, it _might_ be beneficial to hold it in a databse instead of in memory. And not just any database but one that supports queries related to exactly that: spacial positions.

Comment: @Fildor It's actually much more simple than that, just a single X coordinate to represent the position of an object on a conveyor belt. If I was dealing with Cartesian or Quaternion coordinates I would of thrown in the towel months ago and taken my smooth brain to work at McDonalds.

Comment: Ah, I see ... yep, that sound fairly doable in-mem.

Answer (score 2):

You could do

```cs
people.Any(x => x.Age <= 50 && x.Age >= 30)
```

It'll return a bool of whether any age has a value of 30-50